# Value of the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^3} \, dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Evaluate
$ \displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^3} \, dx$.

(I am relatively confident of my answer below but I would still like to make sure that it is correct.)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^3} \, dx &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \frac n{x^3} \, dx \\
&= -\frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n{x^2} \bigg\vert_n^{n+1} \\ 
&= \frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac 1n - \frac n{(n+1)^2} \right) \\ 
&= \frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)^2} \\ 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+1)^2}+ \frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n(n+1)^2} \\ 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+1)^2}+ \frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1n - \frac 1{n+1} \right) - \frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+1)^2} \\ 
&= \frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n+1)^2} + \frac 12 \\ 
&= \frac 12\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac 1{k^2}+\frac 12 \\ 
&= \frac 12\left(\frac{\pi^2}6-1 \right)+\frac 12 \\ 
&= \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{12}}
\end{align}

Comment: You have a mistake in the second-to-last line. $k$ should range from $2$ to $\infty$. (Indeed, otherwise (1) you have a division by zero; (2) the change of indices is objectively incorrect; and, more subjective, (3) you get that extra $\frac{1}{2}$ in the result that "looks" uncanny.) Besides that, the rest (what is before) looks fine.

Comment: And now you have a mistake in the last line, after your edit. The $\frac{1}{2}$'s cancel.

Comment: It looks correct to me, now. (Conditioned on my not having overlooked anything.)